# how to use Caman.js on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, image, camanjs

I am trying to implement an image manipulation library such as Caman.js on  Tumblr theme, but it doesn't work. I have seen examples like this: https://gist.github.com/dashr/3592432#file-tumblr-caman-bfly-xing-js 
that make me think it is possible to do.

I hosted the library on my website and included it in the theme html, but is there a specific way to include this library on Tumblr?

I want to apply the same change to every image in every post. 
This code doesn't do anything ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#right').children('.post').each(function() {

        Caman( this, function () {
          this.greyscale();

          });

          this.render();

        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to select the image in each post. Something like `$('.post').find('img').each`.

Comment: @mikedidthis I changed it, and it still doesn't work..

`$('#right').children('.post').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);    //get container
        $img = $this.find('img');
    Caman($img, function() {
          this.sepia(60);
        this.render();

    });
});`